# How to query random item with Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm just curious is there any way to query a random item from Realm? I need to get 4 random items from my realm + one particular item with ID specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I don't know of a method in Realm to get a random object, but you can do it as described below.

One way of doing this would be to query all objects, then generate 4 random numbers (from 0 to size of RealmResults) and just get objects at those positions, eg. this is how to get one random object:

```
// get realm
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

// get all objects
RealmResults<YourObject> results = realm.where(YourObject.class).findAll();

// random generator
Random r = new Random(System.nanoTime());

// generate first random number to be from the range [0..number of objects)
int firstRandomNumber = r.nextInt(results.size());

// get first object from results at position randomly generated above
YourObject firstRandomObject = results.get(firstRandomNumber);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks!  But is there any method to get count of all the records and then just make random IDs and query database for this ids. Sounds like a plan!

Comment: RealmObjects doesn't have a stable indexes you can query, so something like the above would be the correct way of doing it. Note that everything in Realm is lazy-loaded, so the above is pretty performant as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to get unique results you can use this function, in this function we return a RealmList of n elements from a realmresult:

```
    //Realm result
    RealmResults<Question> questionRealmResults = QuestionManager.getAllQuestions();
    //Realm List to be returned
    RealmList<Question> realmList = new RealmList<>();
    //List of unique random questions ids
    List<Integer> questionIds = new ArrayList<>();
    //Random Instance to generate Questions Ids
    Random random = new Random();

    int randomNumber;

    while (questionIds.size() < limit) {
        randomNumber = random.nextInt(questionRealmResults.size());
        if (!questionIds.contains(randomNumber)) {
            questionIds.add(randomNumber);
            realmList.add(new TestQuestion(questionRealmResults.get(randomNumber)));
        }


    }
```