# Fetch a random record from a Realm database (Swift)

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to fetch a random record from my Swift Realm database.

I have previously used the `sample` function in mongoDB, so I thought there must be an equivalent in Realm (it's based on mongoDB, right?)

I can't find any documentation on such a function, and I've only found search results which suggest to fetch the entire collection then choose a random record [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658856/swift-2-how-can-i-get-a-random-realm-object-within-my-database), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523165/how-to-query-random-item-with-realm)]. Obviously, this is inefficient.

Am I missing something obvious, is there a better way to do it?

See below for an example mongoDB query:

```js
db.Words.aggregate([
{ $match: { gender: gender } },
{ $sample: { size: 1 } }
])
```

Comment: I don't think realm is based off of mongodb, before mongodb acquired realm, it was seen as more of an alternative to sqllite but with an orm by default.

Comment: @BillHaggerty Realm used to be a separate database but when MongoDB bought Realm, the core database has been morphed to be more in-line with MongoDB Atlas to provide synchronization services with Atlas. So now-days its very much aligned with Atlas - in fact the code in the question bypasses Realm completely and queries the server directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity the code in the question is not part of the [Realm Swift SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/) for local or sync but it is a query directly to Atlas using app services, so it would be valid for non-sync'ing or non-local applications. (Use the Swift SDK if possible!)

If we're doing this using the SDK, you can actually leverage high-level Swift functions to return a result using `.randomElement()`

So given a PersonClass that has a name property

```
class PersonClass: Object {
   @Persisted var name = ""
}
```

we can this use this code to return a random person from Realm and output their name to console

```
if let randomPerson = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).randomElement() {
    print(randomPerson.name)
} else {
    print("no data was returned)")
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I was able to add the `match` filter like this: ``let randomWord = Words.where { ($0.gender == gender) }.randomElement()``